# Can You Find Any Error in This Connectivity With Ajax code? I can not get any output from this

Tags: mysql, ajax, connectivity

Here in this code I am fetching records from mysql with the use of ajax technology. But I have some error in this. Kindly say me what is my fault.

```
demo.html file:
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Demo Program</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function myfunction(){
        var myvar;
        try{
          myvar = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        catch(e){
          try{
            myvar = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
          }
          catch(e){
            try{
              myvar = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(e){
              alert("Your Browser Does Not Support");
              return false;
            }
          }
        }

        myvar.onreadystatechange = function(){
          if(myvar.readyState == 4){
            var blankdiv = document.getElementById("blankdiv");
            blankdiv.innerHTML = myvar.responseText;
          }
        }

        var age = document.getElementById('age').value;
        var wpm = document.getElementById('wpm').value;
        var sex = document.getElementById('sex').value;

        myvar.open("GET","demo.php",true);
        myvar.send(null);
      }
    </script>

    <form name="myform" method="post">
      Max Age: <input type="text" name="age"></input><br><br>
      Max WPM: <input type="text" name="wpm"></input><br><br>
      Sex:
      <select name="sex">
        <option value="M">M</option>
        <option value="F">F</option>
      </select>

      <input type="submit" onsubmit="myfunction()" value="Click Here"></input>
    </form>

    <div id="blankdiv">Resul Will Be Here</div>
  </body>
</html>


demo.php file:

<?php
  $host = "localhost";
  $db = "demodb";
  $user = "root";
  $pass = "";

  mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
  mysql_select_db($db);

  $age = $_POST['age'];
  $sex = $_POST['sex'];
  $wpm = $_POST['wpm'];

  $query = "SELECT * FROM demodb WHERE sex = '$sex'";
  $query_result = mysql_query($query);
?>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Sex</th>
    <th>WPM</th>
  </tr>

<?php

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_result)){
      echo "
        <tr>
          <td>$row['name']</td>
          <td>$row['age']</td>
          <td>$row['sex']</td>
          <td>$row['wpm']</td>
        </tr>
      ";
  }
?>
</table>
```

I can not find any output from this...please help me. I have tried alot to solve this still not finding what is the error in this.

Comment: What do you get if you put `console.log(myvar);` after this line `myvar.onreadystatechange = function(){`

Comment: No output is generated...only HTML form elements are as it is and get blank